# return a sorted array but check if its empty or not

Tags: java

A newbie in java.

I am trying to implement some of the basic algorithms in java.

But I am unable to think about this fundamental case..

```
public int[] sort(int[] input){

 if (input.length == 0 ) // return error?? but how

 if (input.length == 1) return input

 //sorting algo

}
```

whats a good way to throw error for empty array?

Comment: You could use `if (input.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array should be of non-zero length")`. The other option is to use assertions to check array length.

Comment: Why not just return input itself? An empty array is sorted by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be the responsibility of the `sort` function to return an error given an empty array, it should just return an empty array.  A well behaved *generic* function shouldn't throw an error for what in normal circumstances is a perfectly valid input.

If an empty array is an error for some other semantic reason, that should be detected *by the caller* of the function beforehand.

If in your particular application you want to avoid the repetition of performing a zero-length check before each `sort` call, write a wrapper function that explicitly calls out the zero length behaviour and then invoke that instead, e.g.:

```
public int[] sortNonEmptyArray(int[] input) {
    if (input.length == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty array passed");
    }
    return sort(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either return an [**IllegalArgumentException**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) with a message saying that empty array is not allowed as the argument, or you can define your own custom error class. The first one is preferable as it's more simple.

However, you can run into trouble if you use some sort of [**divide-and-conquer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) sorting algorithm, and in one step of recursion you pass in an empty array to this method, which is considered sorted (sorted array with zero elements, yes, that can happen). In that case, you should simply return your empty array as return value (it will also form one of your base conditions in recursion).

Answer (score 1):

```
  public int[] sort(int[] input) {
     if (input==null||input.length == 0) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty array");
     }
     //sorting algo
     return input;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the convention set in `java.util.Arrays#sort` and return the empty array.

[Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29)